# Adding a menu bar extra on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, nsstatusbar

I am trying to create an application that will display a menu bar extra on macOS.

I used a lot of code I've found on the web so far, but, while all of them compile, none actually display the menu.

The code snippets are more or less like this:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(
            withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusBarItem.button?.title = ""

        let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "Cap Status Bar Menu")
        statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu

        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Order a burrito",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.orderABurrito),
            keyEquivalent: "")

        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Cancel burrito order",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.cancelBurritoOrder),
            keyEquivalent: "")
    }

    @objc func orderABurrito() {
        print("Ordering a burrito!")
    }

    @objc func cancelBurritoOrder() {
        print("Canceling your order :(")
    }
```

Nothing is displayed on the menu. Is there anything I need to enable to make it display the menu? I tried with images as well, it didn't work either.

Comment: The documentation for `statusItemWithLength:` says: "The receiver does not retain a reference to the status item, so you need to retain it. Otherwise, the object is removed from the status bar when it is deallocated." Perhaps you should try keeping a strong reference to your `statusBarItem`?

Comment: Thanks @TheNextMan. That's what I am doing with `var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!`, but maybe it needs to be outside the class?

Comment: I never wrote any swift code before, but it appears that your `statusBarItem` variable drops out of scope at the end of the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and will therefore be released. You need to keep a reference at the class level (a class member or property).

Answer (score 2):

Funny.  I did the same tutorial, and I did not have any issues.

https://8thlight.com/blog/casey-brant/2019/05/21/macos-menu-bar-extras.html

Here is what is in my code.

--

```
// at the top
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

// first lines of the class AppDelegate

var window: NSWindow!  // I don't think this is important

var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

// top lines of applicationDidFinishLaunching

// Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
let contentView = ContentView()

// Menu Bar Extras
let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system

statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)

statusBarItem.button?.title =  ""

let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "Cap Status Bar Menu")

statusBarMenu.addItem(
    withTitle: "Order a burrito",
    action: #selector(AppDelegate.orderABurrito),
    keyEquivalent: ""
)

statusBarMenu.addItem(
    withTitle: "Cancel burrito order",
    action: #selector(AppDelegate.cancelBurritoOrder),
    keyEquivalent: ""
)

statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu

// the rest is window creation code

// more methods of the AppDelegate
// make sure this part of the code is correct to be
// "superstitious"; maybe Xcode does not behave properly
// with the @objc keywords/modifiers/decorators
@objc func orderABurrito() {
    print("Ordering a burrito!")
}

@objc func cancelBurritoOrder() {
    print("Cancelling order...")
}
```

Otherwise, I would suggest doing the tutorial over again in case you did not see something the first time.  Good luck, and happy coding.